# If I have two text fields how do I make it so that if one is starting typing in one text field the other one is automatically signatured?

Tags: javascript, pdf

i am new to JavaScript and want to link two text fields in PDF so that if i start typing in one of them, it generates signature in the other one

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)? Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. **If** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: The [onkeydown](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) event should be useful to you.